# Jquery option as a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I have a static option in my Jquery extension. The option is color:"blue"

> $(ele).test({color:"color"});
>
> //I tried this below
>
> var anoption= "color"; $(ele).test({anoption:"blue"});

But it didint work. Is there anyway to serialize another variable into an option name as attempted above?

Comment: Please explain more what you'd like to do, you question is barely understandable and vague :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects simply don't work that way. If you want to set a property of an object where the name of said property is contained in a variable, you must do it using bracket notation. For example,

```
var options = {}, anoption = "color";
options[anoption] = "blue";
$(ele).test(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your going to want to make a function like below:

```
function changeColour(colour,ele){
    $(ele).css({'color':colour});//this will change the colour of the text
}
```

Now to run this function you'll need to call it. So lets put a function call on an element. we can do this two ways. One within the javascript `document.ready` function on on the element it's self.

jQuery selector function:

```
$('#element').click(function(){
    changeColour('#FF0000',$(this)); //this will send the colour: #FF0000 being red and your element.
}
```

Within the element itself:

```
<div id="element" onClick="changeColour('#FF0000','#element')">
    <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

Now there is an easier way to do this using jQuery:

```
$('#element').click(function(){
   $(this).css({'color':'#FF0000'});
});
```